# How to sum up all the lines in the table below that are not FALSE without SUMPRODUCT

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumproduct

I need your help to sum up all the lines in the table below that are not FALSE...

Here's what I'm doing so far, for each line:

```
=IF(OR(A1="En cours";A1="Engagé"); NETWORKDAYS.INTL(IF(MONTH(NOW())=MONTH(B1);B1;EOMONTH(TODAY();-1)+1);IF(MONTH(NOW())=MONTH(C1);C1;EOMONTH(TODAY();0));"1110111";holidays) * 7 * D1)
```

- if A is "Engagé" or "En cours"
- then I want to count the number of Thursdays within the current month
- and multiply that number by 7 and then D...

Can you help me, please?

[image]

Also, [Here's the link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oGOKeAt7Or7BumkolqU-YE6mkMrzvxiTfnUS8Tnq6HU/edit?usp=sharing).

Thanks! ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM` or `SUMIF`.

Using `SUM` will not recognize non numerical data, `FALSE` will be ignored.

```
=SUM(F1:F124)
```

For `SUMIF` you can use:

```
=SUMIF(F1:F124, ">0")

 or 

=SUMIF(F1:F124, "<>FALSE")
```

### References

- [SUM(range)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en)
- [SUMIF(range, criterion)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583)